# Sum elements in array using x87 floating point assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, x87

I am trying to get the sum of the array using x87, but the output is displayed as 0. From my understanding, the sum at the end should be in eax. What can be done to fix this?

```
int main() {

   float price[ ] = { 22.1, 34.44, 567.33, 2.45 };
   float sum= 0;


   __asm {

                        xor edx, edx //counter
                        mov ebx, 4 //num elements in array
                        lea ecx, price //address of first element in array
                        fldz

                    L1 :
                        fld dword ptr[ecx + edx * 4]
                        fadd
                        dec ebx
                        jz done

                        inc edx
                        jmp L1

                    done :
                        mov sum, eax    
   }

   cout << "sum= " << sum; 

   return 0
}
```

Comment: I don't quite see where you ever assign a value to `eax`.  Why do you expect `eax` to hold the sum?  Try to replace `mov sum, eax` with `fstp sum`.

Comment: *should be in eax* - What makes you think so?  fadd works with FPU registers.  Have you stepped thru this with a debugger?

Comment: My apologies, I did not transfer the code over correctly; however, fuz's suggestion solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @triassiic If you have solved your problem, add an answer to your own question.  Do not simply go and edit the question such that it can no longer be understood.  Remember: Stack Overflow is supposed to be a reference site for future visitors, not just for you.

Comment: This will fail for larger arrays because you'll overflow the x87 register stack (it has 8 registers, st0..st7).  Use `faddp` or `fadd dword ptr[ecx + edx * 4]`.  Also don't forget to increment your pointer inside the loop.